# how to update information in a Table View when user starts typing in the search bar

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to automatically reload a list when the user types into the search bar of a TableView.

I have attempted to do this using my following code. I am able to get the list but even if I type into the search bar, it doesn't "filter" the results.

```
class UsersTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //update the search results
        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }


    @IBOutlet var usersTableView: UITableView!
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
    var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()

    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        let usersRef = databaseRef.child("users")
        let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
        query.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            self.usersArray.append((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary?)!)

            //insert the rows
            self.usersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        print("HOLAAAAAAAAAAA")
        print(self.usersArray)

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        if ((searchController.isActive) && (searchController.searchBar.text != "")){
            return filteredUsers.count
        }
        return self.usersArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let user: NSDictionary
        if ((searchController.isActive) && (searchController.searchBar.text != "")){
            user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]!
        }else{
            user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]!
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = user["email"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user["name"] as? String

        return cell
    }

    func filterContent(searchText: String){
        self.filteredUsers =  self.usersArray.filter({ user in
            let userEmail = user!["email"] as? String
            return (userEmail != nil)
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    }
```

What I expect to get isle verytime that the user starts typing, the list should be displaying only the searches that match the string from the search bar.  But it is not doing it.

Comment: I have a full example of doing this in one of my other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490103/select-filtered-search-results/50490408#50490408). I removed the [xcode] tag as the issue isn't directly related to which IDE you use

Comment: From what I can see is that you are filtering the user not by the `searchText`, but instead by checking if the user has an `email`-address. Are there any users inside your database that don't have an `email`-address and therefore are not being displayed when you type something into the search bar?

Comment: As @AndréKuhlmann stated you are not using the `searchText: String` value in the `filterContent` func.

Comment: Thank you that was it I forgot to add a line of code