# how to search the table data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My requirement : I will be having a list of chat details in a table view.On top of table view ,there will be a search functionality using text field.based on unique id of user, search should get done.if there is no chat with the unique id, which the user entered,then it has to redirect to another screen which is called chatcreatepage. when ever we are searching chat, we will be using an api called FIND API and in that FIND API there is a chat dictionary,if it is null,then create chat will get called.If that chat dictionary is not nil then need to display that chat details in chat list table view. When the chat list page is loading then ,we will be calling  Chat list Api.when we are searching the chat by entering the unique id in textfield,we will be getting the corresponding details of that entered unique id & that unique id details we have to show in the table view.

This is the task and i have done till the chat list showing in the table.I am really not aware of this search result showing after calling the FIND API.If anyone helps me to solve it, would be really great.Thank in advance.I am providing the code below.

```
     import UIKit
        import Alamofire
        import SwiftyJSON
        import SDWebImage
        class ChatlistViewController: UIViewController{
             var pro = [[String:Any]]()
             var dict:[String:Any]!
             var idd = ""
             var id = ""
            var chatt:Dictionary = [String:Any]()
            var searchActive : Bool = false
            var filtered:[String] = []
            var data:[String] = []

            @IBOutlet weak var search-text: UITextField!
            @IBOutlet weak var chatlisttable: UITableView!
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                       apical()

            }



            func apical(){

                let acce:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-tokenn")!
                        print(acce)

                        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(acce)","Content-Type":"application/X-Access-Token"]

                Alamofire.request(Constants.Chatlist, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {  response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        print(response)
                        if response.result.value != nil{
                            var maindictionary = NSDictionary()
                            maindictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                            print(maindictionary)

                            var userdata = NSDictionary()
                            userdata = maindictionary.value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary

                            var productsdetails = [[String:Any]]()
                            productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as! [[String:Any]]
                            self.pro = productsdetails
                                 print(self.pro)
                                   self.chatlisttable.reloadData()

                        }else{
                            let Alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No data found ", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                            Alertcontroller.addAction(CancelAction)
                            self.present(Alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                                break
                            case .failure(let error):

                                print(error)
                            }
                        }


            }

            func searchapicall(){
                idd = searchtext.text!
               let acce:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-tokenn")!
                print(acce)

                let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(acce)","Content-Type":"application/X-Access-Token"]
                print((Constants.Chatlistsearch)+(idd))
                Alamofire.request((Constants.Chatlistsearch+idd), method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {  response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        //print(response)
                        if response.result.value != nil{
                            var maindictionary = NSDictionary()
                            maindictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary

                            var chat:Dictionary = maindictionary.value(forKey: "data") as! [String:Any]

                            var chattt:Dictionary = chat["chat"] as! [String:Any]

                            if (chattt != nil) {

                                print("Find Action")

                                self.chatt = chat["user"] as! [String:Any]
                                print(self.chatt)
                                //var uniqued:String = self.chatt["unique_id"] as! String

                            }else{
                                let viewc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as? ChatViewController
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewc!, animated: true)
                            }

                        }else{
                            let Alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No data found on this unique id", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                            Alertcontroller.addAction(CancelAction)
                            self.present(Alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        break
                    case .failure(let error):

                        print(error)
                    }
                }

            }




        }


        extension ChatlistViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

            func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

                self.searchapicall()

                return true
            }

        }

        extension ChatlistViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                if (searchActive == false){
                return self.pro.count
                }else{
                    return 1
                }
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                var cell = chatlisttable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatlistTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatlistTableViewCell

                if (searchActive == false){

                dict = pro[indexPath.row]
                var recepient = dict["recipient"] as! [String:Any]
                print(recepient)

                var name = recepient["name"] as! String
                print(name)
                id = recepient["unique_id"] as! String
                print(id)
                var image = recepient["avatar"] as! String
                print(image)
                cell.namelbl.text = name
                cell.idlbl.text = id
                cell.imageView!.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Mahi.png"))

                }else{

                    cell.namelbl.text = chatt["name"] as! String
                    cell.idlbl.text = chatt["unique_id"] as! String
                }

                return cell
               self.chatlisttable.reloadData()

            }

        }

//Response format

{
    "success": 1,
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "unique_id": "10002",
            "name": "nani",
            "avatar": "https://www.planetzoom.co.in/storage/user/avatar/AkgcUFF3QIejMhZuLF4OXnSFHjxNAOo4FuXV3Mgi.jpeg"
        },
        "chat": null
    }
}
```

Comment: you would likely be best using UISearchController. I have an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490103/select-filtered-search-results/50490408#50490408

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UISearchBar and in call your api in delegate method of searchbar func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String).
For reference use this https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Search-Bar-Guide